# AngularJS ui-router: ui-sref links aren't prepending the hash when filling in href values

Tags: angularjs, hash, angular-ui-router, href, ui-sref

My ui-router state provider is setup like so:

```
.state(
    'events', {
        url: '/events',
        templateUrl: ...,
        controller: ...
    })
.state(
    'events.listEvents', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: ...,
        controller: ...
    })
.state(
    'events.eventDetails', {
        url: '/details',
        templateUrl: ...,
        controller: ...
    })
```

I start off in `events.listEvents` state, so my URL looks like this:

```
https://baseUrl.com/home#/events/list
```

and I have a link on that page like this:

```
<a ui-sref="events.eventDetails">event details</a>
```

When I just click the link normally, **it works correctly** and routes me to a page with the URL:

```
https://baseUrl.com/home#/events/details
```

but when I try to open that same link in a new tab (or when I right-click and copy the "href" link address), it's incorrect:

```
https://baseUrl.com/events/details
```

**So the question is:** Why is the *ui-sref* filling in the wrong *href* value?  Why is it totally missing the **#** hash in the URLs it's generating? (And yes, I already tried enabling/disabled $locationProvider.html5mode and that didn't have any effect on this.)

Comment: Why the `/home?user=jeff` in the `events.listEvents` URL?

Comment: It's just meant to illustrate that the application has a base URL (`/home` in this case) which remains constant as the ui-router state changes. As you switch between states, the `/home` remains the same, and only the stuff after the # pound sign changes. You can ignore the `?user=jeff` if you want - it's part of the base URL, so it remains constant as you navigate around the application.

Comment: Edit: I cleaned up my sample URLs here to make it easier to read

Comment: I had this issue, but upgrading ui-router fixed it, so I guess it was a bug that got fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added this to my main `app.js` as a workaround:

```
.run(['$state',
    function($state) {
        $state.originalHrefFunction = $state.href;
        $state.href = function href(stateOrName, params, options) {
            var result = $state.originalHrefFunction(stateOrName, params, options);
            if (result && result.slice(0, 1) === '/') {
                return '#' + result;
            } else {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
])
```